# How to select html option value in php while loop?

Tags: php

I have following code in php `while` loop and here you can see a html `select` tag.

I want to `selected` it's option value if `$status = 1` or `$status == 2`. It's mean `Active` or `Blocked`

In this loop it's always selected `Blocked` option which Is `$status == 2`

But there are only 1 blocked data in my mysql database. What I am doing wrong here ?

**PHP While Loop**

```
$data = array();
$x = 1;
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array(); 

    $nestedData[] = $x;
    $nestedData[] = $row["user_id"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["address"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["package_name"];

    $status       = $row['status'];
    if( $status == 1) {
        $statusMsg = "selected = 'selected'";
    } elseif( $status == 2 ){
        $statusMsg = "selected = 'selected'";
    }

    $nestedData[] = "
    <select class='form-control' name='status' id='changeStatus'>
        <option value=''>--Select--</option>
        <option value='1' $statusMsg>Active</option>
        <option value='2' $statusMsg>Blocked</option>
    </select>";

    $client_id = (int) $row['client_id'];
    $nestedData[] = "<a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' href='{$site_url}toplevel/clients/update/$client_id'>Edit</a>&nbsp;<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'  data-id='$client_id'>Delete</a>";

    $data[] = $nestedData;

    $x++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$statusMsg` will always be output as `selected = 'selected'` on both tags regardless if the `$row[status]` is 1 or 2.

You need to add another variable to distinguish between the two tags and clear both variables at the start of the loop.

```
$status       = $row['status'];
$statusMsg1 = "";
$statusMsg2 = "";

if( $status == 1) {
    $statusMsg1 = "selected = 'selected'";
} elseif( $status == 2 ){
    $statusMsg2 = "selected = 'selected'";
}

$nestedData[] = "
<select class='form-control' name='status'>
    <option value=''>--Select--</option>
    <option value='1' $statusMsg1>Active</option>
    <option value='2' $statusMsg2>Blocked</option>
</select>";
```